# CakePHP HABTM – List all related items

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm very new to CakePHP (and only slightly less new to MVC concepts) and am trying to build a system with a HABTM relationship between `events` and `participants`. I'd like the index page to display a list of events in a table, with one cell of each row containing a full list of participants. So far, my table display loop code looks like:

```
<?php foreach ($events as $event): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $event['Event']['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['Event']['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php       
            foreach ($participants as $participant):
                echo $participant['Participant']['name'];
            endforeach;
        ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I know this is wrong, but I've tried many variations on this theme (all of which seem to my mind as equally wrong), such as `$event['Participant']...` and nothing works. I know the answer is simple, but I don't know what it is and searching around just gives answers to similar, but not sufficiently similar, answers. What do I need to write?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this considering `recursive` IS NOT `0` in your controller.

```
<?php foreach ($events as $event): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $event['Event']['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['Event']['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php       
        foreach ($event['Participant'] as $participant):
            echo $participant['name'];
        endforeach;
    ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is untested. So if you need anymore help on this solution, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks very much. I independently came up with a similar solution earlier and it appears to do exactly what I want it to do.